# Creating a Details template View from Viewmodel in mvc using Entity Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a Details View where i can have all the data displayed from an entity DataModel:
This is the ViewModel:

```
     public class SubjectOverviewViewModel
        {
            [DisplayName("Neptunkód")]
            public Subject NeptunId{ get; set; }
            public SubjectContent TaFoAdatok { get; set; }
            public SubjectContent TaAdatok { get; set; }
            public SubjectContent TaOktatok { get; set; }
            public SubjectContent TaKurzusok { get; set; }
            public SubjectContent IrodalomLista { get; set; }
            public virtual SubjectContent SubjectContent { get; set; }

            public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
        }
```

This is the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Details(SubjectOverviewViewModel model,string id)
            {

                return View(model);
            }
```

And the View:

```
@model irfwebpage.ViewModels.SubjectOverviewViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>SubjectOverviewViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subject.NeptunId)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Subject.NeptunId)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubjectContent.TaFoAdatok)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SubjectContent.TaFoAdatok)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubjectContent.TaAdatok)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SubjectContent.TaAdatok)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubjectContent.TaOktatok)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SubjectContent.TaOktatok)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubjectContent.TaKurzusok)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SubjectContent.TaKurzusok)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubjectContent.IrodalomLista)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SubjectContent.IrodalomLista)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subject.Name)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Subject.Name)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id = Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

[image: And this is on the website]
The website is looking like this after i launch it. I dont know what seems to be the problem. Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is showing that way because the model you are passing into the view has no values for the propertie `Subject` and `SubjectContent`.

To make sure your view is displaying the model properly, you can create a dummy `SubjectOverviewViewModel` in code and then pass that to the view in your controller. Once you get that working, then you know all is well. After that you can get it from a datasource and if there is a problem, you know it is not with the display and the problem is with the code that gets things from the datasource. I am not sure if you are familiar with unit testing, but it will be very beneficial here. If you are not, just hardcode it and then once you have the display working,  you can comment it out and work on the part of getting it from datasource.

Having said that, I am not sure what it is you are trying to do. I think what you want is 2 actions:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    // This will be GET action.
    // Notice this only has one parameter: string id
    // The browser will pass in an id, and your controller will get the 
    // info related to that id to display it.
    // Write code here to get the data for your viewmodel from a datasource.
    // Normally this will be a database or a web service. There are many
    // different ways you can achieve this: some people use a repository 
    // pattern.
    // To get the display working, you can just create a dummy one here 
    // and once you know it is displaying, you can then comment it out or 
    // totally remove it.
    return View(model);
}
```

Then you need a second action:

```
public ActionResult Details(SubjectOverviewViewModel model)
{
    // This will be a POST action
    // Notice the parameter here is SubjectOverviewModel. 
    // Normally this will be passed in after the user has filled our some 
    // form. You will perform validation here and if it is valid, then you 
    // will save it to the datasource (database etc.). 
    // Once you save to the database send a redirect (RedirectToAction) to 
    // tell the user everything was successful. Use the PRG pattern here.
    return View(model);
}
```

You can read more about PRG pattern [here](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-post-redirect-get-pattern/).